# how to monitor servers properly with nagios?

Tags: monitoring, nagios, nrpe

Currently, I'm using nrpe to monitor clients using Nagios but when nrpe goes down then all the stat goes to an unknown state which causes it difficult to monitor critical alerts...
What and how should I prove so that I never miss critical alerts?

Comment: Not found much details about it :(

Comment: Could you [edit] your question and say more about how "nrpe goes down"? In my memory, nrpe is a remote daemon on the monitored servers and checks are run from the nagios server with a check_nrpe command. What's failing exactly?

Comment: It sounds like your actual question is "why is nrpe crashing", but you don't provide any logs or any information on what happens when it goes down.